# how to check an empty input and regulate the type of input in perl

Tags: perl

Guys how do i check an empty input in perl? Including spaces,tabs,newlines etc..

here's my sample code but its not working: what am i doing wrong?

```
my $number=int (1+rand 100);

while (<>) {
    chomp $_;
    last if ($_=~/exit|quit/i or $_ eq $number);
    print "too high! \n" if (defined $_ && $_ > $number);
    print "too low!\n" if (defined $_ && $_ < $number);
    print $_;

}
```

So basically, the user input something, if it's a number it compares to the default random number. It prints low or high depending on the number. But when i just press enter without entering something it still goes to that if statement and gives an error that what i entered isnt numeric (due to this code $_ < $number).

So another question is how to handle input to allow only the word "exit" or "quit" and numbers. Other than that it exits.

Answer (score 1):

The `while(<>){...}` will loop as long as the return value of the `<>` is defined, i.e. you aren't at EOF. So `$_` is always `defined` inside the loop.

To assert that some input is numeric, you can use `looks_like_number` from [Scalar::Util](https://metacpan.org/module/Scalar%3a%3aUtil) or use a simple regex:

```
unless (/\A[0-9]+\z/) {
  print "not numeric!\n";
  next;
}
```

After that, we can treat the value of `$_` as a <del>number</del> integer, and can be sure that `use warnings` won't complain. E.g.

```
# remove newline from input
chomp;
# Test for abort condition
last if /\b(?:quit|exit)\b/;
# Assert numeric input
unless (/\A[0-9]+\z/) {
  print "not numeric!\n";
  next;
}
# Check input against secret $number
if ($_ == $number) {
  print "Correct!\n";
  last;
} elsif ($_ < $number) {
  print "too low\n";
} elsif ($_ > $number) {
  print "too high\n";
}
```

Comment: no, the while loop will not terminate on empty input. i tested it. Instead i got an error saying that "" is not numeric

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the silly question, Got the answer to my first question.

you just have to add this code to the first condition

```
 $_=~/^\s*$/
```

which compares if the input is any whitespace

and for the second one to limit only the "exit" and "quit" as a valid non digit input add this one to the first regex comparison in the first condition

```
$_=~/(exit|quit|\D)/i
```

notice the \D which only matches non digit characters. But since its an "OR" it will short circuit once a specific non digit character (exit or quit) is entered, terminating the loop instantly.

Thanks guys

Comment: Note: the `\D` character class can include many numeric characters that Perl can't convert to a number—the `\D` generally sees numbers in the Unicode sense. The charclass `[^0-9]` (match anything that can't be an ASCII integer digit) may be slightly more correct.